# cv::Exception at memory location

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new in openCV and I have many problems using it.
I have to work with a pointer on a cv::Mat and I can't even initialize it:

```
cv::Mat* _image_3D = new cv::Mat();
*_image_3D = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
Point3f vt = (Point3f)_image_3D->at<uchar>(0,0);
std::cout << vt.x << " " << vt.y << " " << vt.z<< " ";
```

I thought that `zeros` would initialize my Matrix, so normally it's possible to access the first point of the matrix, but when I execute the code I get this error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x761cb727 in glwidget.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002eeda0.`

`glwidget` is my application

I tried to do this to a Matrix that I loaded and  it worked:

```
 Mat mat = imread( "..XXX.jpg",0);
 Point3f vt = (Point3f)mat.at<uchar>(0,0);
 std::cout << vt.x << " " << vt.y << " " << vt.z << " ";
```

I need actually to access/edit the pixels of my matric !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a 3 channel float Mat initialized to Zero using

```
cv::Mat image_3D(height, width, CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

or

```
cv::Mat image_3D = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32FC3);
```

Furthermore your access with `at<uchar>()` is wrong. It should be (e.g.)

```
Point3f vt(cv::Vec3f>(0,0));
```

(although there are many possible permutations, such as `Point3f vt = mat.at<Vec3f>(0,0);`)

In your code, `Point3f vt = (Point3f)mat.at<uchar>(0,0);` *may* work for you because
`at<uchar>()` returns a reference to a single byte, and when you cast it to a Point3f  the correct data is adjacent to that byte. Without a deeper knowledge of C++ I wouldn't expect this to work on every compiler.
**However:** for me with VS2012 in release mode both of your access methods yield the same incorrect data, and in debug mode both fail the assertion in `at<>()` because the size of a uchar is not the same as `elemSize1()` for the Mat.
Perhaps you used debug mode for your first case, and release mode for the second?

If you are accessing your pixels sequntially, `at<>()` isa n inefficient way to do it. See http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way

Comment: Why does 'at work with the matrix that i loaded and not with the other ?